# Getting my Symfony pull request merged

Tags: symfony, pull-request

One month ago I submitted a pull request for what I believe is a backwards-compatibility break in Symfony 2.7:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/15328

No one in the core team has reviewed it yet, which is surprising to me since I would have thought BC-breaks would be a high priority. I've read the [contributing guidelines](http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/patches.html) and followed them as best I can; the only problem I see is that it's not passing on HHVM for reasons that I don't think have to do with my change.

So my question is: have I missed some prerequisite for getting one's PR reviewed, or do I just need to quit whining and be patient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot talk on behalf of the core team or direct experience. In fact I should not talk at all :-)

But as an occasional open source maintainer myself, I see that there are 222 PRs open; as long as yours is failing the CI tests, I fear it will definitely get less attention than the others. Also it may have been triaged as a less important fix. Again, this is just IMHO.

I think you should really focus on fixing the broken CI test; you can ask another question here to get help.

Comment: P.S. all said and done, thank you for contributing to open source. Keep doing it and please do not be discouraged by this delay.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In thinking about how to pass the failing tests, I decided the best thing was to update and rebase my changes to the most recent version -- perhaps the failing tests were fixed in the meantime. Turns out that other tests are now failing, but I think this is a good approach in general!